# What would be the likelihood function of a pdf, $p(n)=1-|n|$ for $|n|<1$?

Tags: probability, self-study, density-function, likelihood

This might seem like a basic question to some but I am utterly confused by the fact that the given pdfs are not Gaussian or any other distribution commonly seen in examples.

I have two hypotheses

$H_0: y(t)=n(t)$

and

$H_1: y(t)=s(t)+n(t).$

The samples of noise $n(t)$ have the pdf $p(n)=1-|n|$ for $|n|<1$ and those of signal $s(t)$ have a value of $1$.

What would the likelihood functions be?

Comment: The phrasing "s(t) has a pdf of 1" does not  make sense.  Usually, s(t) would be a parameter that would be estimated (or a function of one or more parameters).  Also the pdf for n(t) is a trianglar distribution, with parameters (-1,0,1).

Comment: Corrected the phrasing of the question, hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: There's discussion of the behaviour of the likelihood for data from a triangular distribution [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/64103/805) of which your specific null and alternative are special cases.

Comment: But if your problem is really as stated the log-likelihood ratio will go to either positive or negative infinity if even a single data point is below 0 or above 1.

Answer (score 3):

$Y$ is a random variable whose *density* $f_i(y)$ when $H_i$ is the true hypothesis
is given by
$$\begin{align}
f_0(y) &= \begin{cases}1-|y|, & -1 < y < 1,\\0,&\text{otherwise,}\end{cases}\\
f_1(y) &= \begin{cases}y, & 0 < y < 1,\\
2-y, & 1 \leq y < 2,\\0,&\text{otherwise,}\end{cases}
\end{align}$$
making the likelihood ratio 
$$\Lambda(y) = \frac{f_1(y)}{f_0(y)}
= \begin{cases}0, & -1 < y < 0,\\
\frac{1-y}{y}, & 0 < y < 1,\\
\infty, & 1 < y < 2,\\
\text{undefined}, & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$
More to the point, when $H_0$ is the true hypothesis, *all* the observations $y_i$
necessarily are in the interval $(-1,1)$, and if at least one of them is negative,
the *decision* is that $H_0$ is indeed the true hypothesis (with no possibility
of a false alarm or making a Type I error and no need to think about $p$-values
or similar things dear to the heart of the hypothesis-tester).
Similarly, when $H_1$ is the true hypothesis, *all* the observations $y_i$
necessarily are in the interval $(0,2)$, and if at least one of them exceeds $1$,
the *decision* is that $H_1$ is indeed the true hypothesis (with no possibility
of a false dismissal or making a Type II error and no need to think about $p$-values).  It is *only* in the case when *all* the observations $y_i$
are in the interval $(0,1)$ that we need to consider the likelihood ratio
or the log-likelihood ratio, and there exists the possibility that we might
make a Type I or Type II error. In other cases, we have an instance of
what some people call *singular* detection: there is no possibility that
the decision is incorrect.